# Azure: How do I tell which services are IaaS1 vs IaaS2 since I can see services in both new and old portal?

Tags: azure, azure-management

Am trying to help a customer move their services from an Azure Direct subscription to a CSP subscription. In the guides I've found, the approach used for IaaS1 (the old/class Azure - ASM) differ from what's used if a client's services all belong to IaaS2 (the new portal - ARM).

My confusion arises from the fact that while things like Class VMs can be easily identified if one views a client's services under the new portal - they are annotated as "Classic", am not so sure about any other services originally created under the ASM model.

And to further complicate things, it seems as though, viewing a client's services in the classic portal shows both ASM and ARM services, and this, without any means of distinguishing between them!

So, how do I go about this?

Comment: `And to further complicate things, it seems as though, viewing a client's services in the classic portal shows both ASM and ARM services` .... Are you sure about this? I don't think it is possible to view services deployed via ARM in the old portal.

Comment: why not? if you deploy the classic resources

Comment: The new ARM IaaS v2 resources will not show up in the classic portal.

Comment: @AndyShen alright then. So that means, since I can see all his resources in both portals, they must be all classic?

Comment: Yes. You can also confirm with Find-AzureRmResource with resource type parameter using Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualmachines and Microsoft.Compute/virtualmachines for classic VMs and ARM v2 VMs respectively. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/powershell-azure-resource-manager#search-for-resources